# how to get selected tab and send to print function?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have these tabs:

```
<a href = "#" title="Print" role="button" id="print" onclick="print()" class = "btn btn-default btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> </a>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li><a href="#floor1" data-toggle="tab" data-id="1"><span>1st Floor</span> </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#floor2" data-toggle="tab" data-id="2"><span>2nd Floor</span> </a> </li>
        <li><a href="#floor3" data-toggle="tab" data-id="3"><span>3rd Floor</span> </a> </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="tabContents">
        <div class="table-responsive tab-pane fade active in" id="floor1">
            <p>Details on floor 1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive tab-pane fade" id="floor2">
            <p>Details on floor 2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="table-responsive tab-pane fade" id="floor3">
            <p>Details on floor 3</p>
        </div>
     </div>
```

Whenever i click the print anchor i would want to print the content of the current active tab. But i have a problem on how to get the current tab to be sent to a print function. Can any one help me out? Thanks.

I have this print function.

```
function print()
            {
              var divToPrint=document.getElementById("floor1").innerHTML;
              newWin= window.open("");
              newWin.document.write(divToPrint);
              newWin.print();
              newWin.close();
            }
```

Comment: I’d just use a print stylesheet that has everything but the active tab set to `display:none` …

Comment: yeah, all i want to do is identify what tab is active that that's what will be printed.

Comment: It looks like your active tab already has a class `active` set … so what’s the problem …?

Comment: oh i mean when i select floor 2 then i click the anchor it would print only the contents in floor2 div.. and so on.. so my question would be how to determine that in the print function?

Comment: You don’t do that in the print function, that’s a case for your print _stylesheet_ …

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
<a  ...onclick="return print()" ....></a>
```

OR

```
<input type="button" onclick="print()" .......>
```

instead of anchor tag